# Why do I get a "We found a problem with some content in '.xlsm'" message, everytime I automatically calculate a sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a piece of code that is extracting calendar events from A google calendar that is connected to my excel. It runs perfectly, however every time I add code to update a certain sheet("Calendar"), save, and close. I am prompted with the following message the next time I open the file again:
We found a problem with some content in '.xlsm'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

Note this only happens when I add: Sheets("Calendar").Calculate, or Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic for the workbook. I also tried introducing a checkbox and only if the check box is checked and the macro is ran the sheet will be updated. That prompted the same error. When there is no calculate code this message does not pop up.

I am baffled and couldn't find a similar situation with a sheet calculating being the cause. I appreciate any help.

None of the code gets lost or altered, the file just comes up as [Repaired]

```
    Sub listlist()
Dim olApp As Object, olNS As Object, olFolder As Object, olApt As Object, NextRow As Long, FromDate As Date, ToDate As Date, z As Integer, num As Integer
Sheets("Calendar").Columns("A:B").ClearContents

num = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value - month(Now)
FromDate = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 0 + num) + 1
ToDate = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 1 + num)


On Error Resume Next
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err.Number > 0 Then Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = olNS.Folders("Internet Calendars").Folders("Calend")

NextRow = 2


With Sheets("Calendar")
    .Range("A1:C1").Value = Array("Project", "Date", "First Trim")
    For Each olApt In olFolder.Items
        If (olApt.Start >= FromDate And olApt.Start <= ToDate) Then
            .Cells(NextRow, "A").Value = olApt.subject
            .Cells(NextRow, "B").Value = CDate(olApt.Start)
            NextRow = NextRow + 1
        Else
        End If
    Next olApt
    .Columns.AutoFit
End With

Set olApt = Nothing
Set olFolder = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

'Sort
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = Sheets("Calendar").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Calendar").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B2").End(xlDown) _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With Worksheets("Calendar").Sort
    .SetRange Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Lastrow, 3))
    .Header = xlYes
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With


Sheets("Calendar").Calculate


'Update Meeting dates

    z = 3

    For j = 2 To 20
        If Sheets("Calendar").Cells(j, 5).Value <> "" Then
        For I = 2 To 160
            If Sheets("Consultants").Cells(I, 15).Value = Sheets("Calendar").Cells(j, 5).Value Then
                For h = 9 To 160
                    If Sheets("Consultants").Cells(I, 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(h, 2).Value Then
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(h, 4).Value = Sheets("Calendar").Cells(j, 2).Value
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next h
            End If
        Next I
        End If
    Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: You can try by creating a new sheet, copy&paste the content of the current sheet, then delete the current sheet, rename the new sheet  and retry (**make a backup of your file before**, but you have this probably already) - or maybe even by creating a brand new file and copy everything (don't forget the code). It may be that the recalculation just is a symptom and there is already something corrupt before

Comment: I only needed to calculate a range, so I went ahead and only put the calculate formula for that range. So the problem may stem in that range, the range has excel formulas in it, I feel like if I manage to input the formulas through vba while creating a new sheet like you suggested, that might fix it. That brings concern to another question, Why is this error happening if the macro is not automatically running, the macro only runs when I click a button.

Comment: No clue, from my point of view a corruption should never happen and at the end is caused by a (Microsoft) bug within Excel. The message you get is only a symptom of a deeper problem, and my experience is that it goes away when starting with a new workbook or -sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by using @FunThomas 's suggestion. I started the workbook from scratch and did the following things:

-Inputted formulas through vba instead of leaving the cells in excel populated with the formulas
-changed clear columns A & B to clear all cells since I know manually input the formulas

By doing this I have no need to calculate the sheet anymore. I did not test implementing calculate into the workbook, I do not want to risk anything getting corrupted.